# I am trying to start new activity through intent but facing this error

Tags: android-studio

> I am working on multiple Activities and i got this error while using
> context -  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method
>
> > 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null
> > object reference

```
public class myadapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Asia, myadapter.myviewholder> {

    private Context context;
    Asia asiaData;
```

> I have created the context constructer

```
    public myadapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Asia> options, Context context, Asia asiaData) {
        super(options);
        this.context = context;
        this.asiaData = asiaData;
    }

    public myadapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Asia> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull Asia asia) {
```

> I got error on null reference on Context

```
        final Asia temp = asiaData;

        holder.tvName.setText(asia.getConName());
        holder.tvCap.setText(asia.getCapital());
        Glide.with(holder.img.getContext()).load(asia.getImg()).into(holder.img);

        holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(context, MainActivityCountry.class));
                intent.putExtra("name", temp.getConName());
                intent.putExtra("capital", temp.getCapital());
                intent.putExtra("desc", temp.getDesc());
                intent.putExtra("img", temp.getImg());
                context.startActivity(intent);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            }
        });
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
        return new myviewholder(view);
    }


    /* ******** VIEW HOLDER ********** */

    class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView img;
        TextView tvName, tvCap;

        public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvCap = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCap);


        }
    }
}
```

> Here is the Activity where i have call the adapter

```
package com.example.recyclerview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class ActivityAsia extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView rv;
    Context context;
    Button btn_addCountry;
    myadapter adapter;
    ImageView img;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        setTitle("Recycler View");
        rv = findViewById(R.id.rView);
        btn_addCountry = findViewById(R.id.btn_addCountry);
        img =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Asia> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Asia>()
                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Asia"), Asia.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new myadapter(options);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        btn_addCountry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityAsia.this, AddItemAsia.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

}
```

Comment: please share your activity code where u call adapter.?

Comment: I am not calling the adapter in the other activity. i am using intent to pass data to display in second activity

Comment: i'm talking about "myadapter" this apdater ...where did u call this adapter... share those code.

Comment: I have shared the code. Please review

Comment: ok wait for my ans

Answer (score 0):

In your **ActivityAsia** activity call adapter like this

```
 adapter = new myadapter(ActivityAsia.this,options);
 rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and in your **myadapter** like this

```
public class myadapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Asia, myadapter.myviewholder> {

private Context context;
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Asia> options;



public myadapter(Context context,@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Asia> options) {
    super(options);
    this.context = context;
    this. options = options;
}


@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull Asia asia) {

    final Asia temp =  options;

    holder.tvName.setText(asia.getConName());
    holder.tvCap.setText(asia.getCapital());
    Glide.with(holder.img.getContext()).load(asia.getImg()).into(holder.img);

    holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(context, MainActivityCountry.class));
            intent.putExtra("name", temp.getConName());
            intent.putExtra("capital", temp.getCapital());
            intent.putExtra("desc", temp.getDesc());
            intent.putExtra("img", temp.getImg());
            context.startActivity(intent);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        }
    });
}


@NonNull
@Override
public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
    return new myviewholder(view);
}


/* ******** VIEW HOLDER ********** */

class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView img;
    TextView tvName, tvCap;

    public myviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvCap = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCap);


    }
 }
}
```